# Кэширование ajax содержимого jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

На сайте есть `tabs` с загружаемым содержимым `jqgrid` и прочее ui. Задача разделить их загрузку и выполнять по нажатию на вкладку. В данный момент при загрузке страницы грузятся все вкладки, и при переходе по ним также перезаливаются с сервера.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ 
    cookie:{expires:20},
    cache: true,
    'ajaxOptions':{ cache:false },        
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        var cache = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'cache');
        console.log(cache);
    }
});//Tabs
```

Не кэширует почему-то.
 
*jQuery UI 1.12.1*

Возможно ли реализовать средствами виджета нужную загрузку или пытаться делать свои вкладки?

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
    // if the target panel is empty, return true
    return ui.panel.html() == "";
}
```

Ссылка на источник: [Cache JQuery UI-Tabs Ajax loaded Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19712131/5275890)